# How can I tell if I'm in a child shell

Tags: bash, shell

If I'm using bash and type `bash` I'm in the child shell and need to type `exit` to go back to the original parent shell. If I forget which one I'm in how do I check?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `SHLVL` environment variable.

**man bash:**

> **SHLVL** : Incremented by one each time an instance of bash is started.

```
$ echo "$SHLV"
1

$ bash

$ echo "$SHLV"
2

$ exit

$ echo "$SHLV"
1
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an inferior answer but you can also use pstree:

```
$ pstree -s $BASHPID
systemd───systemd───gnome-terminal-───bash───pstree
$ bash
$ pstree -s $BASHPID
systemd───systemd───gnome-terminal-───bash───bash───pstree
```